# Delete from table where key not found in other table?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Table 1:

- id
- name

Table 2:

- id
- other_table_id
- table_1_id
- ..

Basically what I want to do is

```
Delete from table_1 
where id not in (select table_1_id 
                 from table_2 
                 group by table_1_id);
```

Which should work, what I am wondering is if the sub query is the best way to do this/ is there any other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I prefer to use `JOIN` over *subquery*.

```
DELETE a FROM table_a a
            LEFT JOIN table_2 b
                ON a.ID = b.table_1_id
WHERE   b.table_1_id IS NULL
```

- [**SEE SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0150/1)